# Looking for Blender .exe or source that works with windows 10

Tags: installation, windows

I used to be able to use Blender and build it a few years back. I am experiencing that any version available from blender.org does not react appropriately.

I am wondering if you have the correct git c/c++ source repository. Then I will just build it. I have tried this too and don't know who got the stuff man!!! LOL.

Can anyone provide me a download link, ftp or another get method of the sources?

Comment: afaik, recent blender versions should work with windows 10 also... (sorry but I have different OS) what you mean by "any version available from blender.org does not react appropriately."?

Comment: Blender works just fine on Windows normally. I have it running fine and many other people do as well. If you can describe the issue or problem, we may be able to help.

Comment: I use Blender 2.78 with Windows 10 with no issues. As long as you download from https://www.blender.org/download/ it should run fine normally.

Comment: Thank you much. I ws using blender.org/download a while ago when I was testing this issue and found that there was a version that operated normally and lightning fast. The version I now have you have to click the center restore to get it to do anything and I don't know the command to get it to function correctly at startup of blender.exe. That took place too. So I have pulled the daily release for 64 bit and found it has the same unresponsive issues. I know there is a C,C++ or C# version that works differently. Lightning fast with many options all you really need for a whole Entertainment.sln.

Comment: Well can anyone at least provide me with Cloning into 'release/datafiles/locale'... remote: Repository not found